# Convert word-files to txt files

Tags: vba, ms-word, data-conversion, converters

I have a lot of folders. Each folder has one word-document.

I now want to convert each word-document to a txt-document, save all txt-document in one separate folder and give them the name of the folder (of the word-document).

I actually have no idea about how to start. I have some PHP-knowledge but actually never created a script/macro like this case - and that's the reason why I even don't know how to google for an easy solution the right way to get further information.

Of course, you don't need to present me the whole script, but I would really appreciate to get some information about how to start and where I could get further information.

Thank you so much!

Comment: SO is meant that you have one specific question, eg "How do I save a word doc as text", or "How do I loop over all files in a folder". Your question is far to broad - you should focus on one problem at a time. Just as a hint: Word has a "SaveAs"-functionality that allows you to save a Doc as Plain Text, so at least you don't have to bother about how to extract text from a word doc. For looping over files and folders, have a look at "FileSystemObject" - numerous examples on SO and elsewhere.

Comment: Cross-posted (in a thread that already answers the question in full) at: https://www.excelforum.com/word-programming-vba-macros/918937-batch-convert-docx-to-txt.html. For cross-posting etiquette, please read: http://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?184

Answer (score 1):

If you need to convert multiple Word files to other formats, like TXT, RTF, HTML or PDF, run the script below.

```
Option Explicit On

Sub ChangeDocsToTxtOrRTFOrHTML()
    'with export to PDF in Word 2007
    Dim fs As Object
    Dim oFolder As Object
    Dim tFolder As Object
    Dim oFile As Object
    Dim strDocName As String
    Dim intPos As Integer
    Dim locFolder As String
    Dim fileType As String
    On Error Resume Next

    locFolder = InputBox("Enter the folder path to DOCs", "File Conversion", "C:\Users\your_path_here\")
    Select Case Application.Version
        Case Is < 12
            Do
                fileType = UCase(InputBox("Change DOC to TXT, RTF, HTML", "File Conversion", "TXT"))
            Loop Until (fileType = "TXT" Or fileType = "RTF" Or fileType = "HTML")
        Case Is >= 12
            Do
                fileType = UCase(InputBox("Change DOC to TXT, RTF, HTML or PDF(2007+ only)", "File Conversion", "TXT"))
            Loop Until (fileType = "TXT" Or fileType = "RTF" Or fileType = "HTML" Or fileType = "PDF")
    End Select

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set oFolder = fs.GetFolder(locFolder)
    Set tFolder = fs.CreateFolder(locFolder & "Converted")
    Set tFolder = fs.GetFolder(locFolder & "Converted")

    For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
        Dim d As Document
        Set d = Application.Documents.Open(oFile.Path)
        strDocName = ActiveDocument.Name
        intPos = InStrRev(strDocName, ".")
        strDocName = Left(strDocName, intPos - 1)
        ChangeFileOpenDirectory tFolder
        Select Case fileType
        Case Is = "TXT"
                strDocName = strDocName & ".txt"
                ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:=strDocName, FileFormat:=wdFormatText
        Case Is = "RTF"
                strDocName = strDocName & ".rtf"
                ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:=strDocName, FileFormat:=wdFormatRTF
        Case Is = "HTML"
                strDocName = strDocName & ".html"
                ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:=strDocName, FileFormat:=wdFormatFilteredHTML
        Case Is = "PDF"
                strDocName = strDocName & ".pdf"
                ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:=strDocName, ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF
        End Select
        d.Close
        ChangeFileOpenDirectory oFolder
    Next oFile
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```